# Why is my title not centre to the middle inside FlexibleSpaceBar under SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been struggling and wondering which part of my code went wrong. My title inside FlexibleSpaceBar under the SliverAppBar is not centered to the middle after I upgrade my flutter version to the latest. Before my update, it was still in the middle now it becomes like this:

[image]

Code:

```
  SliverAppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        pinned: true,
        snap: true,
        floating: true,
        expandedHeight: 160.0,
        flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Matematik'),
          background: Icon(Icons.calculate, color: Colors.white, size: 50), 
        ),
      ),
```

Hope to get any help! I got a feeling is a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default padding for `title` which is kind of 72 on start.

```dart
final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding = widget.titlePadding ??
   EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
        start: effectiveCenterTitle && !(settings.hasLeading ?? false) ? 0.0 : 72.0,
        bottom: 16.0,
        );
```

You can provide the padding.

```dart
flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(),
  title: const Text(....
```